# no such file to load -- active_support/core_ext (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my rails 2.3.8 app running in windows 7, getting the following error when attempting to start the server:

```
D:\app1>ruby script/server
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require': no such file to load -- active_support/core_ext (LoadError)
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
        from D:/app1/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support.rb:56
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
        from D:/app1/vendor/rails/railties/lib/commands/server.rb:1
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
        from script/server:3
```

In the custom require file block below... line 36 is "gem_original_require path"

```
  def require(path) # :doc:
    gem_original_require path
  rescue LoadError => load_error
    if load_error.message =~ /#{Regexp.escape path}\z/ and
       spec = Gem.searcher.find(path) then
      Gem.activate(spec.name, "= #{spec.version}")
      gem_original_require path
    else
      raise load_error
    end
  end
```

gem list as follows:

```
actionmailer (2.3.8)
actionpack (2.3.8)
activerecord (2.3.8)
activeresource (2.3.8)
activesupport (2.3.8)
builder (3.0.0)
calendar_date_select (1.16.1)
cgi_multipart_eof_fix (2.5.0)
gem_plugin (0.2.3)
google4r-checkout (1.0.6.1)
i18n (0.5.0)
liquid (2.2.2)
money (3.5.5)
mongrel (1.1.5 x86-mingw32)
mysql (2.8.1 x86-mingw32)
rack (1.1.0)
rails (2.3.8)
rake (0.8.7)
rmagick (2.12.0 mswin32)
```

Looked around with portions of the error, but I'm not quite sure where to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a file name

> core_ext.rb

in the

```
 C:\Ruby\lib\ruby\gems\1.8\gems\activesupport-2.3.8\lib\active_support
```

and edit add the content to the following lines

```
filenames = Dir["#{File.dirname(__FILE__)}/core_ext/*.rb"].sort.map do |path|
  File.basename(path, '.rb')
end

# deprecated
filenames -= %w(blank)

filenames.each { |filename| require "active_support/core_ext/#{filename}" }
```

Comment: that directory already has the same file with the exact contents you provided. thank you for trying.

Answer (score 5):

Just looking at the stack trace ... it looks like your application is on drive "D" and the ruby files are on drive "C".

Maybe when its performing the require

```
filenames = Dir["#{File.dirname(__FILE__)}/core_ext/*.rb"].sort.map do |path|
  File.basename(path, '.rb')
end
```

its requiring that path on "D" when it should be on "C". That's my best guess. Good luck.

Comment: this was so long ago and I don't have the machine that the error was created on so +1 for the possible solution... I'm sure it will help someone else.